# vue-element-admin+laravel10 front-end separation project, nginx deployment, back-end interface 404

Tags: nginx, vuejs2, laravel-10

## I don’t know if it’s a pagoda nginx configuration problem. If I write in location / {alias /www/wwwroot/web-admin/dist/;}, the home page will be blank, css and js files will report 404, and I can only write them outside, and then The judgment of intercepting the request to admin-api does not take effect, the interface will be 404, ask for advice![enter image description here

**nginx**

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name test.cn;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.htm default.html;
    root /www/wwwroot/web-admin/dist/;

    #SSL-START SSL相关配置，请勿删除或修改下一行带注释的404规则
    #error_page 404/404.html;
    #SSL-END

    #ERROR-PAGE-START  错误页配置，可以注释、删除或修改
    #error_page 404 /404.html;
    #error_page 502 /502.html;
    
    # 默认访问前端项目
    location / {
        #解决页面刷新404问题
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    # 后端项目
    location ~ ^/(admin-api) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    
    #ERROR-PAGE-END

    #PHP-INFO-START  PHP引用配置，可以注释或修改
    include enable-php-81.conf;
    location ~ \.php(.*)$
    {
        root  /www/wwwroot/api-admin/public/;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi-81.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        include pathinfo.conf;
    }
    #PHP-INFO-END

    #REWRITE-START URL重写规则引用,修改后将导致面板设置的伪静态规则失效
    include /www/server/panel/vhost/rewrite/test.cn.conf;
    #REWRITE-END

    #禁止访问的文件或目录
    location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.env|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md)
    {
        return 404;
    }

    #一键申请SSL证书验证目录相关设置
    location ~ \.well-known{
        allow all;
    }

    #禁止在证书验证目录放入敏感文件
    if ( $uri ~ "^/\.well-known/.*\.(php|jsp|py|js|css|lua|ts|go|zip|tar\.gz|rar|7z|sql|bak)$" ) {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
    {
        expires      30d;
        error_log /dev/null;
        access_log /dev/null;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
    {
        expires      12h;
        error_log /dev/null;
        access_log /dev/null;
    }
    
    # 前端静态资源处理
    location  ^~ /images/ {
        alias /www/wwwroot/web-admin/dist/images/;
    }

    # 后端静态资源处理
    location  ^~ /storage/ {
        alias /www/wwwroot/api-admin/public/storage/;
    }
    access_log  /www/wwwlogs/test.cn.log;
    error_log  /www/wwwlogs/test.cn.error.log;
}
 server {
   listen       9527;
   server_name  localhost;
  
   # 接口代理，用于解决跨域问题
   location /admin-api {
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    
     # 后台接口地址
     # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9527/admin-api;
     # proxy_redirect default;
     # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
     # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers X-Requested-With;
     # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS;
   }
 }
```